# Video/Audio in today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget

Would be possible to play video or audio in today extension? 
I know that you can't do audio, because today extension is separated binary so if you turn off screen also audio will go off. But what if I hit play button in today extension and audio would be playing through the app user installed with extension?

And with video, is possible to watch video in today extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically possible:

- Play audio clips while notification center is open
- Have a button that opens up your host app, which in turn starts background audio

Technically not possible:

- Play audio in the background (see [Today Extension and background audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095687/today-extension-and-background-audio))

Don't know about video.

If you want to submit your app to the App Store:

- Play audio clips: Your app might get rejected
- Play video: My gut feeling is that it will very likely be rejected
- Have a button that opens up your host app: Will be rejected, if this is the main function of your widget